# SQL need help building a query

Tags: sql

I need your help building a query.

I have two tables:

The first table (table1) gives me the historical status , all the status that my product passed and the second table(table2) tells me the status at this moment for my product.

the id columns are the same for both tables like the status column.

I want to build a query that tells me the amount of my products that are with the status D,E and F in my  table 2 but on my table 1 didn't passed for the status C, like going to status B to status D,E or F without passing to C.

I tried running this query:

```
select count(id), status 
from table1 e 
where status not in (C) EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                FROM table2 c 
                                WHERE e.id = c.id 
                                  AND status IN (D,E,F))
group by status
```

The query didn't return with the expected results. Can you help?

Comment: given that the query has syntax errors, you shouldn't have gotte any results at all. do you really have fields named `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f`? Or are you just typing up the query by hand here and forgot to quote those strings?

Comment: Just typing up the query by hand here and forgot to quote those strings. The name of my fields it's different in my tables.

Comment: `not in (c) exists` is also wrong. you should show the ACTUAL query, even if you do have to censor field names. There's no point in asking for help on what isn't actual code.

Comment: That's my query , I only censored the field names. I'm new to sql. What can I put instead of  not in (c) exists since its wrong ?

Comment: `not in ('C') OR EXISTS ...` maybe. but `...(c) exists ...` is a flat-out syntax error.

Comment: I fix it to : select count(id) ,status from table1 e 
where status not in ('C')   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table2 c WHERE e.id = c.id and  status in ('D','E','F'))
group by status but it didn't return the expected results . . It gives me the results where the status is 'D','E' 'F' but not the status that not passed trough'C'.

Comment: I need a query that gives me the number of products that are in status 'D','E' and 'F ' but not passed through the status 'C'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other responders noted, you have some syntax errors. Basically, you're just missing a few words.

```
select    count(id) 
          , status 
from      table1 t1 
where     status not in ('C')   
          *and* 
          EXISTS (
                 SELECT     * 
                 FROM       table2 t2 
                 WHERE      t2.id = t1.id 
                            and status in ('D','E','F')
                 )
group by status
;
```

Alternatively, you could try solving it this way. Full disclosure - this is probably not as efficient (see [In vs Exists](http://www.gregreda.com/2013/06/03/join-vs-exists-vs-in/)).

```
select   count(id)
         , status
from     table1
where    id not in
         (
         select    id
         from      table1
         where     status not in ('C')

         union 

         select    id
         from      table2
         where     status in ('D','E','F')
         )
group by status
;
```

Comment: No problem! Glad to assist.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(id), status
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.id
and a.status not in ('C')
group by a.status
```